# Cocoapods "use_frameworks!" with Google Analytics and Swift libraries

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I've been using `use_frameworks!` directive so that I can use some dependencies on my project. If I comment that directive, I get a **red** message saying

```
Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is beta. Add 'use_frameworks!' to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.
```

Today I decided to use [Google Analytics for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift) but when running `$pod install` I get

```
The 'Pods-MyProject' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries
```

Googling around I found out it is caused because of the `use_frameworks!` directive and I should remove it. So I'm between a wall and a sword, what can I do to be able to work with these libraries?

PS: We are required to manage dependencies using `Cocoapods`, so including it in a different way is not an option. Also, I don't have a bridging header in my project, but I'm still able to work with libraries using `import MyDependency`

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods 0.37 or better?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 0.37.2

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: I think I solved using bridging header